# How can I set up a watcher to copy files to other files inside same folders?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-sass

Here's what I have so far and what I have tried:

In my application I have files with a structure like this

```
/app/learn/content/ab.html
/app/learn/content/bc.html
/app/learn/content/base.html
/app/write/content/ab.html
/app/write/content/bc.html
/app/write/content/base.html
/app/xx/ab.html
/app/xx/bc.html
/app/xx/base.html
```

I set up a watcher like this:

```
var abc = {
    src: [
        '**/ab.html',
        '**/bc.html',
    ],
}
gulp.task('watchHTMLs', function () {
    gulp.watch(abc.src, function (file) {
        return gulp.src(path.basename(file.path))
          .pipe(rename('base.html'))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
    })
});
```

What I would like to do is to watch for files with ab.html or bc.html file names and then copy these to base.html in the same directory when one changes.  But so far my watcher starts but then nothing at all happens when I change one of the ab.html or bc.html files. The watcher does not even seem to fire.

Can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an unscoped globstar `**` over your entire project is a bad idea. `**/ab.html` matches `ab.html` in all folders of your project including `node_modules`. Depending on how many nested folders there are in `node_modules` this can take a looong time to finish. If it ever does.

Also the `file` you receive from `gulp.watch()` only has an absolute path, so you need to feed the [`base` option](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase) with the current working directory to `gulp.src()`.

Finally you only want to change the name of your `file`, not the entire path. Use the `basename` option of `gulp-rename`.

All this adds up to:

```
var abc = {
  src: [
    'app/**/ab.html',
    'app/**/bc.html'
  ],
};
gulp.task('watchHTMLs', function () {
  gulp.watch(abc.src, function (file) {
    return gulp.src(file.path, { base: process.cwd() })
      .pipe(rename({basename:'base'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
  });
});
```